# Can we create a clustered index and a primary key on two different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Once we declare a primary key, a clustered index is created on the column by default.

Comment: "*a clustered index is created on the column by default*"  - unless you specify the PK as non-clustered

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/02/10/sql-server-primary-key-and-nonclustered-index-in-simple-words/

Answer (score 1):

It is very much possible to have two different columns as a primary key and clustered indexes. But remember, if I create a Primary Key on a table first, a clustered index will also be created.

Now, in case I need them on two different columns, drop the Primary Key constraint and the clustered index shall automatically vanish. Now create a clustered index on column A and declare column B as Primary Key, and column B will have a nonclustered index will be created by default on it instead of a clustered index. This way, we can have two columns as Primary Key and clustered index declared on them.

Comment: You can explicitly specify whether the primary key constraint is clustered or nonclustered, although PKs will be clustered by default if no other clustered index exists.

Comment: I think by default when we create a primary key a clustered index is created.

Comment: PKs will be clustered by default if no other clustered index exists and the clustered/nonclustered specification is omitted.

Comment: @SumeshEs Yes, by **default**, but like Dan said you can specify nonclustered primary key explicitly instead of letting the default occur: `ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,`